# Why does my Dojo Pie chart disappear when i call updateSeries after an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dojox.charting, pie-chart

I am trying to update a dojo Pie chart using the updateSeries method.  I invoke the method after performing an ajax call to get an updated javascript array data.

Here is the Javascript:

```
var eventByReasonsData = .... //gets populated on jsp page compile 

var theme = dojox.charting.themes.Julie;

var eventReasonsChart = null;


function makeEventsByReason() {

    var dc = dojox.charting;
    eventReasonsChart = new dc.Chart2D("eventsByReasonChart");
    eventReasonsChart.setTheme( theme ).addPlot("default", {
        type: "Pie",
        font: "normal normal 8pt Tahoma",
        fontColor: "black",
        labelOffset: -20,
        radius: 100

    }).addSeries("eventSeries", eventByReasonsData );

    var anim_a = new dc.action2d.MoveSlice(eventReasonsChart, "default");

    var anim_b = new dc.action2d.Highlight(eventReasonsChart, "default");

    var anim_c = new dc.action2d.Tooltip(eventReasonsChart, "default");

    eventReasonsChart.render();


}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
        <div id="eventsByReasonChart" ></div>
```

And here is the javascript making the AJAX call:

```
     new Ajax.Request( url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: params,
        onComplete: function(response) {


            if( response.responseText != "empty" )
            {
                var chart = eventReasonsChart;

                eventByReasonsData = response.responseText;

                chart.updateSeries( "eventSeries", eventByReasonsData );

                chart.render();                                                 
            }

        }
    });
```

Lastly, here is how my data is formatted when being sent to the chart:

```
[{ y:48 },{ y:1 },{ y:1 },{ y:14 },{ y:7 },{ y:3 },{ y:8 }]
```

When the Chart is initially drawn, everything is cool, no problems.  AFter making the Ajax call, i receive the new data, the update call is made and the chart disappears.  No errors that I can see on the console.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `eventByReasonsData` is a string, when `updateSeries()` expects an array. You can use `dojo.fromJson()` to convert the string to an array:

```
chart.updateSeries( "eventSeries", dojo.fromJson(eventByReasonsData) );
```

Comment: amazing.  totally worked.  Why does the original chart creation work?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much. That had me stumped for quite some time.

Comment: It worked inertially because the compiler converted the text literal to a proper array. When you transfer in JSON you should do it explicitly.